# Create date range report column using codeigniter 3 excel

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, phpexcel

I want to create export file date-range report using ci.

views.php

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="attn_date" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">From</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="attn_from" name="attn_from">
        <?= form_error('attn_from'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="attn_date" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">To</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="attn_to" name="attn_to">
        <?= form_error('attn_to'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="daily_export_file" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Export Data</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <?= form_dropdown('export_file', ['report' => 'Report'], set_value('export_file'), 'class="form-control" id="export_file"'); ?>
        <?= form_error('export_file'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller.php

```
$querydata = $this->db->query("select a.*, b.* from db_attn a
                                    LEFT JOIN tbl_wrkhour b 
                                    ON b.id_wrkhour = a.wrk_hour WHERE attn_date between '". $this->input->post('attn_from')."' 
AND '". $this->input->post('attn_to')."'order by attn_date desc")->result();

$spreadsheet = new PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
$sheet_name = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Attendance Report");
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumm = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
$dataattn = $querydata;
$sheet->setCellValue('A5', 'No');
$sheet->setCellValue('B5', 'Employee Name');
$sheet->setCellValue('C5', 'Date');
$sheet->setCellValue('D5', 'Detail');
$no = 1;
$rowx = 6;
foreach ($dataattn as $rowattn) {
    $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $rowx, $no++);
    $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $rowx, $rowattn->emp_name);
    $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $rowx, $rowattn->date);
    $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $rowx, $rowattn->attn_detail);

}
```

I've successfully show date range of all employee details. How to transpose the detail of each date?

current view in my export excel file:

| No | Employee Name | Date | Detail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | 03-01-2023 | Present |
| 2 | bbbb | 03-01-2023 | leave |
| 3 | cccc | 03-01-2023 | late |
| 4 | aaaa | 04-01-2023 | Present |
| 5 | bbbb | 04-01-2023 | Present |
| 6 | cccc | 04-01-2023 | Present |

expected change:

| No | Employee Name | 03-01-2023 | 04-01-2023 | next column date range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaaa | Present | Present | next |
| 2 | bbbb | leave | Present | next |
| 3 | cccc | late | Present | next |

Any idea? Please help...

Comment: $dataattn = $querydata; ? you didn't like the name :). You can simply get that using the SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get that from SQL directly

```
select
   no,
   emp_name,
   case 
      when exists (select user was present on time on 03-01-2023) then 'Present'
      when exists (select user was present late on 03-01-2023) then 'Late'
      else 'Absent'
  end as '03-01-2023',
....
```

Answer (score 0):

create a helper array, fill it in foreach function with rules and colums, then set this array to $dataattn.

Comment: Hi, can you add some code? So the asker will have better info.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer